# design pattern to expire documents on cloudant

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

So when a document is deleted, the metadata is actually preserved forever. For a hosted service like cloudant, where storage costs every month, I instead would like to completely purge the deleted documents.

I read somewhere about a design pattern where you use [dbcopy](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/design-documents-get-put-delete-copy.html?highlight=dbcopy#dbcopy) in a view to put the docs into a 'current' db then periodically delete the expired dbs. But I cant find the article, and I don't quite understand how database naming would work. How would the cloudant clients always know the 'current' database name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cloudant does not expose the _purge endpoint (the loose consistency guarantees between the clustered nodes make purging tricky).

The most common solution to this problem is to create a second database and use replication with a validate_document_update so that deleted documents with no existing entry in the target database are rejected. When replication is complete (or acceptably up-to-date if using continuous replication), switch your application to use the new database and delete the old one. There is currently no way to rename databases but you could use a virtual host which points to the "current" database.

I'd caution that a workload which generates a high ratio of deleted:active documents is generally an anti-pattern in Cloudant. I would first consider whether you can change your document model to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted documents are kept for ever in couchdb. Even after compaction .Though the size of document is pretty small as it contains only three fields

`{_id:234wer,_rev:123,deleted:true}`

The reason for this is to make sure that all the replicated databases are consistent. If a document that is replicated on several databases is deleted from one location there is no way to tell it to other replicated stores.

There is [_purge](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents) but as explained in the wiki it is only to be used in special cases.