# What information is stored in a CouchDB 'tombstone' record?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I have a scenario where I am holding personal data.  For privacy reasons I need to ensure that I am not holding onto the personal data for too long.  However, when a document is [deleted](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#delete--db-docid) a tombstone record is still kept on disk.  After I delete a document, can I be sure that the personal data is completely destroyed?

**Question**: What information is stored in the 'tombstone' record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tombstone record only contains the following fields:

- _deleted (boolean flag)
- _id
- _rev

*Source*:  [CouchDB document API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/document/common.html#api-doc-retrieving-deleted-documents)

However, if you have stored sensitive data in the `_id` field, you may need to consider:

- [Purging](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Purge_Documents) the record (Single node CouchDB only)
- Contacting [Cloudant Support](https://cloudant.com/support/) (Cloudant only)

Finally, because we are talking about deleting records, be careful of workloads that generate a high ratio of deleted:active documents as this is considered an [anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905621/1033422).

Comment: Also remember that for CouchDB you will need to call the `_compact` endpoint to remove the bodies of old document revisions.