# Why is a high ratio of 'deleted' to 'active' documents generally considered an anti-pattern?

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

Having a high ratio of *deleted* to *active* documents is generally an anti-pattern in Cloudant and CouchDB (see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22905621/1033422).

**Question:** Why is this an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every document that is [deleted](https://docs.cloudant.com/tutorials/crud/index.html#delete) is replaced with small amount of metadata called a
[tombstone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711862/what-information-is-stored-in-a-couchdb-tombstone-record/26711863#26711863) which is used during replication (a tombstone is also created for each document that is in a [batch delete](https://docs.cloudant.com/tutorials/crud/index.html#id9) operation).

- Although tombstone documents contain only a small amount of metadata, having lots
  of tombstone documents will have an impact on the size of used storage.
- Tombstone documents still show up in [_changes](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/database.html#obtaining-a-list-of-changes) so require processing for replication 
  and when building views.

Comment: So, why this is an anti-pattern?(: Or may be this isn't an anti-pattern at all, just a one of possible state of a database?

Comment: For me the anti-pattern is that many new users coming to CouchDB aren't aware of the consequences of deleting documents and expect DELETE to work the same as in a RDBMS, but in CouchDB relying on heavy DELETEs can lead to performance problems.

Comment: It is possible to reclaim space through PURGE and then compacting, though it is not recommended because it rebuilds all views on the database. If you have to delete a lot, you'd better just create a new database.